# Can Selenium automate iOS Safari webpage tests on a real iPhone?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to automate a website on a real iPhone  with Selenium.  Is that possible or do I need Appium?  Ideally I will launch my tests from my Windows machine via `RemoteWebDriver`

edit: it looks like it might work in iOS 13
https://webkit.org/blog/9395/webdriver-is-coming-to-safari-in-ios-13/

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can test with real devices (iPhone) but you need Appium (I suppose you don't want to spend amount of money for e.g. saucelabs)

We tested this in our company´s project furthermore let me say that for running iPhone you also need an Apple Mac.

Furthermore you will need:

- Ecclipse
- Appium
- XCode
- TestNG
- ...

There are some good tutorials: [Toolsqa-Appium](https://www.toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/appium-test-on-real-ios-device/) and [Automated Testing Appium](https://medium.com/2359media/tutorial-automated-testing-on-ios-with-appium-test-ng-and-java-on-mac-bc115d0ec881)